# Get Option label using Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

```
<select onchange="changeFields(this)" alias="school_type" id="15_4_19" name="15_4_19">
        <option label="" value=""></option>
        <option label="High School" value="8">High School</option>
        <option label="University" value="9">University</option>
        <option label="Elementary Schools" value="10">Elementary Schools</option>
    </select>


console.log(element.getElement('value'));
```

will return selected option value, any body can help me to get the label of the same

ie, instead of 8,9,10 prefer to get High School, University, Elementary Schools.

```
console.log(element.getElement('value'));
```

is not working. Any idea???

Comment: Why did you tag this with jQuery?

Comment: Can we see the `changeFields` function?

Comment: I think a jquery expert can give a spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`element.get('text')`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element-Properties%3atext).

---

Okay, so you're using a JavaScript framework - it's time to start writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Remove that `onchange` attribute from the `<select>`, and then...

```
$('15_4_19').addEvent('change', function()
{
    var selected = this.getSelected(),
        text = selected.get('text');
    console.log(text);
});
```

API reference:

- [`addEvent`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element%3aaddEvent)
- [`getSelected`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agetSelected)

Comment: What's the full code you're using to query the DOM and retrieve the text?

Comment: function changeFields(element, force)
{
  element = $(element);
var option_alias = element.get('alias');
if( option_alias == "school_type") {
     //console.log(option_alias);
     
     console.log(element.get('text'));
   }
}